# Can't get any #includes to work in Matlab/MEX with Visual Studio C++

Tags: matlab, mex

I want to do some simulations that need C++-Code in Matlab. This works like a charm, but as soon as I put in some additional `#include`'s in the C++/MEX-Code I get a ton of error messages like this:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(19) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(19) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(21) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(21) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'abs' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(21) : error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(21) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atexit' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(22) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atof' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(22) : error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(22) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atoi' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(22) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atol' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(23) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bsearch' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(23) : error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(23) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'calloc' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(23) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'div' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(24) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'exit' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(24) : error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(24) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'free' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(25) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'labs' 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib(25) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
...
```

I tried different versions of Matlab, Visual Studio and different C++-Compilers. I have code that works perfectly fine and also tried this with example-code from Mathworks that also works fine.

For testing-purposes I simply put `#include <random>` or `include <algorithm>` on top of working examples and then those error-messages occur. No "file not found"-errors.

Can anybody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here? I didn't change anything in **mexopts.bat** and I believe the right include-directories are in there. Programming in Visual Studio itself works without any problems with those `#include`'s...

Comment: Looks like the file you include is missing something, or you are including a C++ file in a C compilation unit. No idea. Please re-read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: There is no example to give. I can use any code with completely fresh installations and it doesn't work. `<random>` and `<algorithm>` are very basic and should work, too (shouldn't they?). I can use any example-code that come with Matlab or work otherwise...

Comment: Yes, show the (smallest possible) code, including its file name, and how you build it. We need to know exactly what you’re doing. Because you describe surprising behavior, we can only assume you are doing something wrong.

Comment: You are saying that the example works fine, but then you add `#include <random>` at the top and it doesn’t? And that this is a C++ source file?

Comment: @CrisLuengo OK, I got it! It was a *.c-File. When I change it to *.cpp it compiles. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so in hope that other people who run into the same problem have an answer here: My source-files were always *.c - so no C++-files. Changing them to *.cpp solved the problem.